# How to call this completion handler?

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I am working with Swift and I need to call this method for calling of web services. I am confused of getting error in completion handler.

```
func makePost(serverURL: String, params: Dictionary<String,String>, completionHandler:(data:String) -> Void)
```

Comment: That completion handler doesn't seem to received an error.  I would have thought that they would have at least have defined it as data:String? so that a failure could be indicated by a nil string.

Comment: Would you please give me the method for calling, I am stuck at some point. Please add that error and provide me calling data.

Comment: @Kashif i already gave you an answer, check it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your function

```
func makePost(serverURL: String, params: Dictionary<String,String>, completionHandler:(data:String) -> Void) {}
```

You can call it like this:

```
let dic :Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary()
makePost("serverUrl", params: dic, completionHandler: {
    print("\($0)")
})
```

replace the `dic` by your actual dictionary

notice that `$0` is the parameter `data` in your closure

Instead of `print("\($0)")`, you can put your code that you want top pass to the `makePost` function

Answer (score 1):

```
makePost("http://foo.com", params: ["param1":"value1", "param2":"value2"]) { result in
    print(result)
}
```